# How do I keep a running count in DynamoDB without a hot table row?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

We have a completely server-less architecture and have been using DynamoDB almost since it was released, but I am struggling to see how to deal with tabulating global numbers on a large scale. Say we have users who choose to do either A or B. We want to keep track of how many users do each and they could happen at a high scale. According to DyanamoDB best practices, you are not supposed to write continually to a single row. What is the best way to handle this outside using another service like CouchDB or ElastiCache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bucket your users by first letter of their usernames (or something similar) as the partition key, and either A or B as the sort key, with a regular attribute as the counts.

For example:

```
PARTITION KEY | SORT KEY | COUNT
--------------------------------
a             | A        | 5
a             | B        | 7
b             | B        | 15
c             | A        | 1
c             | B        | 3
```

The advantage is that you can reduce the risk of hot partitions by spreading your writes across multiple partitions.

Of course, you're trading hot writes for more expensive reads, since now you'll have to scan + filter(A) to get the total count that chose A, and another scan + filter(B) for the total count of B. But if you're writing a bunch and only reading on rare occasions, this may be ok.